# How to push array of objects on update mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I tried something like this:

query:

```
query = {
      pictures: {$pushAll: files}
}
```

files array look like this:

```
[{ fieldname: 'productPhotos',
        originalname: 'images.jpg',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
        filename: '422e64cfb147eff02fee5166d63939b10564d4ad-images.jpg',
        }]
```

Update mongoose model:

```
 Product.update({ _id: product.productId}, query,...
```

Model look like this for pictures:

```
pictures: [{
        filename: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        }
    }],
```

Problem is array in database not update... Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong way around, and you should use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/). i.e

```
Product.update(
 { "_id": product.productId }, 
 { "$push": { "pictures": { "$each": files } } },
 function(err,callback) {

 }
)
```

So the update operator ( i.e [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) ) is at the root of the update statement followed by the field(s) to apply to.[`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) is a modifier to accept a "list" if content to add as opposed to "singular"

Comment: Thanks, how can I pull single element? Tried like this `{$pull: { pictures: { filename: 'product.png' } } }` but not working...

Comment: @Vladimir That's a different question. If you have to, then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It's clearer that way and how this site works. A clear separation of questions.